# Find method without selecting or activating

Tags: excel, vba, select, find

I fellows. 
Matlab was cool and R as well, but now it's time to VBA Excel.
I want to find in "Sheet2" (column A) one value that is stored in "Sheet1" (cell A1). I could do this using Select and jumping from one sheet to the other, but I want to do it without all this jumps. I want to run my code without having the Excel looking frenetic while the code is running. And I want it to run no matters the Worksheet that I have activated in Excel when I run the macro.
Is that possible? Check my code bellow.
All the best for all of you!

```
Sub FindName()

   Dim Name As String
   Dim TablePosition As Range


   Name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

   'If I insert here: Worksheets("Sheet2").Select 
   'The codes runs but just because I am telling him to move to sheet2
   'Why is it not going to Sheet2 with the instruction bellow?

   With Worksheets("Sheet2").Application.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
         Set TablePosition = _
         .Find(What:=Name, _
         After:=Range("A1").End(xlDown), _
         LookIn:=xlValues, _
         LookAt:=xlWhole, _
         Searchorder:=xlByRows, _
         SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
         MatchCase:=False, _
         SearchFormat:=False)

         If Not TablePosition Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto TablePosition, True
         Else
            MsgBox "Name not specified."
         End If

   End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Application.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
```

is the same as

```
Activesheet.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
```

So unless you're on Sheet2 when your code runs, it will search the wrong sheet.

You should use something like:

```
Dim sht as Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet2")
With sht.Range(sht.Range("a1"), sht.Range("a1").End(xlDown))
'...
```

Comment: Master answer. Theoretical explanation with solution!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slightly different approach to your goal. This function will basically look for the first occurrence of the string `Name` in the `activesheet` provided that you supply a column letter (That would A in your case). It will return the address of the cell a `'N/A'` is if there is no match.

```
Function FindName(Name As String, columnId As String) As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim targetrange As Range
Dim targetsheet As String: targetsheet = ActiveSheet.Name
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(targetsheet)
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnId).End(xlUp).Row
Set targetrange = .Range(columnId & "1", columnId & LastRow)
End With
For Each cell In targetrange.Cells
If cell.Value = Name Then
FindName = cell.Address(0, 0)
Exit Function
Else
FindName = "N/A"
End If
Next
End Function

Sub Main()
Debug.Print (FindName("Hi", "A"))
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub test()
    Dim name$, Rng$, Lrow&
    name = Worksheets("Sheet1").[A1].Value
    Lrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next
    Rng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & Lrow).Find(name).Address
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        With Worksheets("Sheet2")
            .Activate
            .Range(Rng).Select
        End With
    Else
        Err.Clear: MsgBox "Name not specified."
    End If
End Sub
```